# authorize.net DPM Page redirection

Tags: asp.net, authorize.net

I am using SIM and sending user to buy things to Authorizaiton.net .But after successful transaction i am unable to come to our site.How can i make the redirection with the response?

### UI Code :

```
<form id="simForm" runat="server" method='post' action='https://test.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll'>
    <input id="HiddenValue" type="hidden" value="Initial Value" runat="server" />
    <input type='hidden' runat="server" name='x_login' id='x_login' />
    <input type='hidden' runat="server" name='x_amount' id='x_amount' />
    <input type='hidden' runat="server" name='x_description' id='x_description' />
    <input type='hidden' runat="server" name='x_invoice_num' id='x_invoice_num' />
    <input type='hidden' runat="server" name='x_fp_sequence' id='x_fp_sequence' />
    <input type='hidden' runat="server" name='x_fp_timestamp' id='x_fp_timestamp' />
    <input type='hidden' runat="server" name='x_fp_hash' id='x_fp_hash' />
    <input type='hidden' runat="server" name='x_test_request' id='x_test_request' />
    <%--<input type='hidden' runat="server" name='x_relay_response' id='x_relay_response' />
    <input type='hidden' runat="server" name='x_relay_url' id='x_relay_url' />--%>
    <input type='hidden' name='x_show_form' value='PAYMENT_FORM' />
    <input type='submit' value="Make Payment" title="Make Payment" visible="false" runat="server" id='buttonLabel' />
</form> 

       Code Behind :
      protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // start by setting the static values
    string loginID = "LOGIN ID";
    string transactionKey = "TRANSACTION ID";
    string amount = "19.99";
    string description = "Sample Transaction";
    string label = "Submit Payment"; // The is the label on the 'submit' button
    string testMode = "true";

    // If an amount or description were posted to this page, the defaults are overidden
    if (Request.Form["amount"] != null)
    { amount = Request.Form["amount"]; }
    if (Request.Form["description"] != null)
    { description = Request.Form["description"]; }

    // also check to see if the amount or description were sent using the GET method
    if (Request.QueryString["amount"] != null)
    { amount = Request.QueryString["amount"]; }
    if (Request.QueryString["description"] != null)
    { description = Request.QueryString["description"]; }

    string invoice = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmss");

    Random random = new Random();
    string sequence = (random.Next(0, 1000)).ToString();

    string timeStamp = ((int)(DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalSeconds).ToString();

    string fingerprint = HMAC_MD5(transactionKey, loginID + "^" + sequence + "^" + timeStamp + "^" + amount + "^");

    //Print the Amount and Description to the page by placing them in the Spans
    //amountSpan.InnerHtml = amount;
    //descriptionSpan.InnerHtml = description;

    //Update the fields in the actual form 
    x_login.Value = loginID;
    x_amount.Value = amount;
    x_description.Value = description;
    buttonLabel.Value = label;
    x_test_request.Value = testMode;
    x_invoice_num.Value = invoice;
    x_fp_sequence.Value = sequence;
    x_fp_timestamp.Value = timeStamp;
    x_fp_hash.Value = fingerprint;
    //x_relay_response.Value = "TRUE";
    //x_relay_url.Value = "http:mysite.com";


}

// This is a wrapper for the VB.NET's built-in HMACMD5 functionality
// This function takes the data and key as strings and returns the hash as a hexadecimal value
string HMAC_MD5(string key, string value)
{
    // The first two lines take the input values and convert them from strings to Byte arrays
    byte[] HMACkey = (new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding()).GetBytes(key);
    byte[] HMACdata = (new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding()).GetBytes(value);

    // create a HMACMD5 object with the key set
    HMACMD5 myhmacMD5 = new HMACMD5(HMACkey);

    //calculate the hash (returns a byte array)
    byte[] HMAChash = myhmacMD5.ComputeHash(HMACdata);

    //loop through the byte array and add append each piece to a string to obtain a hash string
    string fingerprint = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < HMAChash.Length; i++)
    {
        fingerprint += HMAChash[i].ToString("x").PadLeft(2, '0');
    }

    return fingerprint;
}
```

I am sending data successfully and making the payment.But it's not redirecting me to my site.Any Help?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the relay URLs commented out.  Also, you should not reveal your API key or transaction ID.